# Seemingly identical unixODBC installations, but one works and the other doesn't

Tags: postgresql, macos, unixodbc

I am trying to set up unixODBC to access a Postgres server from multiple (Intel) Mac computers.

The first two machines have `unixodbc` and `psqlodbc` installed using Homebrew. I have tested it using this command:

```
iusql ";Driver=PostgreSQL;Server=172.16.66.30;Port=5432;UID=moshe;Database=appdb;" -v
```

One is working perfectly, and the other is showing the following error:

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect
```

I have compared the Homebrew-installed files on both machines, and they are identical. I have run `odbcinst -j` and confirmed that both machines are looking at the same files. The only relevant config file for this test (since I'm not using a named connection) is the drivers file at `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` which has the following contents on both machines:

```
[PostgreSQL]
Description     = PostgreSQL ODBC driver (Unicode 13)
Driver          = /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so
CommLog         = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

Running `odbcinst -q -d -n PostgreSQL` on both machines confirms that the above information is set correctly.

Why am I getting this error on one machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to be a bug in unixODBC. If the `/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini` and `$HOME/.odbc.ini` files are both empty, this error occurs. If one of those files has a datasource defined (even a non-functional placeholder), the `iusql` command works properly. This is true even though the man page says:

```
A string DSN:

  A string DSN may be provided in its entirety, with no file DSN reference at all:

  $ iusql ";Driver=PostgreSQL Unicode;UID=MyID;PASSWORD=secret" -v
```

which should mean that no DSN is required in the config files either.

Here is the simplest code to put in `$HOME/.odbc.ini` to get rid of the error:

```
[placeholder]
Driver = PostgreSQL
```